# How to use Parallelizable in NUnit?

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

How can I use Parallelizable attribute to run tests nonparallel? I'm using `Selenium` + `NUnit 3.7.1`. I put `[Parallelizable(0)]` in my `TestBase` class, but still tests running parallel. Tests fails on Run All but if I run one by one they pass.

My `TestBase.cs`

```
[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable(0)]
public class TestBase
{
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Browser.Initialize();
    }
}
```

My tests:

```
class  Tests: TestBase
{

    [Test]
    public void TestA()
    {
      // test code here
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestB()
    {
       // test code here
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like you should use the [`[NonParallelizable]`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/NonParallelizable-Attribute) attribute.

Comment: @DavidArno Nothing Changed and `[Parallelizable]` is still supported.

Comment: True, but the [`[Parallelizable]`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parallelizable-Attribute) docs say the `[NonParallelizable]` attribute is now a better choice. So it's got to be worth trying...

Comment: By default, with no parallelizable attributes at all - no tests will run in parallel. I think you may need to look deeper into your problem. If you are running multiple test assemblies together however - these WILL run in parallel by defualt.

Comment: Can you clarify please: are you trying to get test *fixtures* to run in series, or are you trying to get the tests *within* a text fixture to run in series? In other words, where do you want parallelism, and where do you *not* want it?